# Selecting XML-nodes by defined rules using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML-sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequences>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-A</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-A</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>False</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-B</PackageFolder>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-B</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-C</PackageFolder>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageEnd>2019-07-23T18:53:58.392+02:00</PackageEnd>
        </PackageMeta>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-D</PackageFolder>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageEnd>2019-07-23T18:53:58.407+02:00</PackageEnd>
        </PackageMeta>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-C</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-E</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>False</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-F</PackageFolder>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageEnd>2019-07-23T18:53:58.407+02:00</PackageEnd>
        </PackageMeta>      
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-D</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-G</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>True</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-H</PackageFolder>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-E</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-I</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>True</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-J</PackageFolder>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageEnd>2019-07-23T18:53:58.407+02:00</PackageEnd>
        </PackageMeta>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>   
</Sequences>
```

Using XPath I want to select those `<Sequence>`-node(s), that have:

- **At least one active package**:
  A Package is meant "active", when there is NO `<PackageActive>` node OR `<PackageActive>` IS TRUE.
  In the sample XML above Package-A is not active, because `<PackageActive>` is "False".
- **At least one package has no end-time**:
  If all packages of a sequence have an `<PackageEnd>`-node, then the sequence should not be selected.

Till now I have not done anything with XPath at all. For my requirment I got the tip using XPath, but I was not able to figure out on my own even though I was reading through [w3XPath-Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).
I used the following XPath, which has at least the problem, that it won't select the sequence, when `<PackageActive>`-node is set to "True".

```
$Xml.SelectNodes( "//Sequence[.//Package[not( ./PackageActive )] and .//Package[not( .//PackageEnd )]]" )
```

Find some additional information to the example below for a better understanding:

- Sequence-A should be selected
  Package-A won't be processed, but Package-B does NOT contain a `<PackageEnd>`-node and therefore should get processed.
- Sequence-B should NOT be selected.
  Both packages contain a `<PackageEnd>`-node.
- Sequence-C should NOT be selected.
  Package-E is NOT Active and Package-F contains a `<PackageEnd>`-node.
- Sequence-D should be selected.
  Package-G is Active and Package-H also. Both Packages do not contain a `<PackageEnd>`-node.
- Sequence-E should be selected.
  Package-J does contain a `<PackageEnd>`-node, but Package-I is Active.

Comment: So the selected output would be Sequence-A and Sequence-D - including their packages, which in the case of Sequence-A, will have Package-A with `<PackageActive>` being `False`; is that correct?

Comment: @JackFleeting Yes this is correct. It should only filter Sequence-nodes. Thank you for your interrest!

Comment: Can you test `//Sequence[.//Package[not(PackageActive) or PackageActive='True'][not(.//PackageEnd)]]` and see if that fits your needs? In my testing it selects sequences A, D, and E, but doesn't follow your logic exactly (trying to keep it simple to start with).

Comment: @DanielHaley Please tell me what you mean exactly by "but doesn't follow your logic exactly". A first test looked good and I will have a closer look now.

Comment: What I mean is that I'm not checking packages separately to see if they're active or doesn't have an end time. I check both things on a package at once. I don't think that's the same as "_At least one active package_" and "_At least one package has no end-time_". It's more like "At least one active package that doesn't also have an end-time". If it does work for you though, let me know and I'll add a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following xpath expression:

```
//Sequence[.//Package[(./PackageActive/text()='True' or not(./PackageActive)) 
                             and not(.//PackageEnd)]]
```

Selects Sequence-A, Sequence-D and Sequence-E if the xml is exactly as above, but selects only Sequence-D and Sequence-E if `<PackageActive>False</PackageActive>` is added to Sequence-A,Package-B.

Comment: I need a bit of time to test this, but it seems to be fine so far :-) Ofc I will mark this as answer, if OK. Optional: Would you mind to give a short description about the selectors/operators used, so I learn something about it and not just copy+paste this in my code? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you! - I did find the following situation: If I add `<PackageActive>False</PackageActive>` to Package-B, The Sequence-A should NOT be selected anymore, because none of the Packages is active. But it is selected!?

Comment: Would it help, if I would drop the requirement about having NO `<PackageActive>`? So to define, that every package has a `<PackageActive>`-node containing "true" or "false"?

Comment: The current XPath-expression is not working correctly. At the moment it does not select `<Sequence-A>`. You meant, that you will take another look on it. I wanted to ask, if it would be helpful to make changes in the `<PackageActive>`-logic to get it working?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am sorry, but on testing I did still find a problem with the latest XPath expression :-(  I did add `Sequence-E` in the sample XML in the request. This sequence should get selected, but unfortunately it is not.

Comment: Looking great now. Still doing some testing. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @DukeDonnovan - In this case I can say = literally - "my pleasure!"; it's been a while since I've had so much fun working on something like this...

Comment: Glad to hear that :-)

Comment: I did not notice any problems anymore while testing. I did just mark this as answer.
Thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

> Using XPath I want to select those `<Sequence>`-node(s), that have:
>
> At least one active package:
>
> - A Package is meant "active", when there is NO `<PackageActive>` node OR `<PackageActive>` IS TRUE. In the sample XML above Package-A is not
>     active, because `<PackageActive>` is "False".
> - At least one package has no end-time: If all packages of a sequence have an `<PackageEnd>`-node, then the sequence should not be selected.

This expression:

```
/Sequences
  /Sequence
    [SequencePackages
       [Package[not(PackageActive = 'False')]]
       [Package[not(PackageMeta/PackageEnd)]]
    ]
```

Selection ([check here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/901cb9edef9162cb1155b646fcc0691d)):

```
<Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-A</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-A</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>False</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-B</PackageFolder>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>

<Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-C</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-E</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>False</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-F</PackageFolder>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageEnd>2019-07-23T18:53:58.407+02:00</PackageEnd>
        </PackageMeta>      
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>

<Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-D</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-G</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>True</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-H</PackageFolder>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>

<Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-E</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-I</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>True</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-J</PackageFolder>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageEnd>2019-07-23T18:53:58.407+02:00</PackageEnd>
        </PackageMeta>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
```

**Do note:** comparison in XPath are existencial comparison. Also, sequence C is selected because your description doesn't match your expected output regarding the independence of both conditions.

Comment: What if there's a `<PackageActive>whatevs</PackageActive>`? That shouldn't be an active package per _`<PackageActive>` IS TRUE_

Comment: @DanielHaley Yes, but then, `PackageActive` wouldn't be a boolean field as it is right now, thus the expression should change accordingly.